# How to add a string in list in column and then preprocess it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a below data frame file with two columns "Message" and "name".

```
data = [['Extension of Time to Comply with Mandatory Disclosure', ['Order']], 
    ['I electronically filed the foregoing document', ['Hearing', 'Urgent']], 
    ['Said oral examination', ['Pleading', 'My Filings']],
    ['In the event of this cause', ['Discovery', 'My Filings']],
   ['A true and correct copy', ['My Filings']],
   ['A credible explanation of human error', ['Urgent']],
   ['Oral examination error', ['Urgent', 'My Filings']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Message', 'name'])
```

I have to do two things using pandas.

1. In "name" column if there is only "Urgent" or "My Filings" or both but not anything else in list then add "Uncategorized" in the list. Like below image.
   [image]
2. After that if there is "['Urgent']" in name column, move it in the next column called "urgent_flag" else write "['Unflag_urgent']". Or if there is "['My Filings']", move it in the next column called "myfilings_flag" else write "['Unflag_myfilings']". Or if there is both "['Urgent', 'My Filings']", then move "['Urgent']" in "urgent_flag" column and "['My Filings']" in "myfilings_flag" column. Like below image.[image]

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a function or you can decide to write a few apply statements.

If you want to write 4 lines of code to get this done, here is how to do it.

```
df['new_name'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: ['Unauthorized'] if all(y in ('Urgent', 'My Filings') for y in x) else x)
df['new_name'] = df.new_name.apply(lambda x: [y for y in x if y not in ('Urgent', 'My Filings')])
df['urgent_flag'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: ['Urgent'] if any(y in 'Urgent' for y in x) else ['Unflag_urgent'])
df['myfilings_flag'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: ['My Filings'] if any(y in 'My Filings' for y in x) else ['Unflag_myfilings'])

print (df.iloc[:,1:]) #ignoring first column as its irrelevant for this problem statement
```

The output will be:

```
                      name        new_name      urgent_flag      myfilings_flag
0                  [Order]         [Order]  [Unflag_urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
1        [Hearing, Urgent]       [Hearing]         [Urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
2   [Pleading, My Filings]      [Pleading]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
3  [Discovery, My Filings]     [Discovery]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
4             [My Filings]  [Unauthorized]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
5                 [Urgent]  [Unauthorized]         [Urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
6     [Urgent, My Filings]  [Unauthorized]         [Urgent]        [My Filings]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your df provided, you can add each column individually using assign and use the `.map()` function on the `name`column.

```
res = (
    df
        .assign(
            # assign first column and use .map() on name column
            urgent_flag = lambda x : x.name.map(
                # perform if-else-based check
                lambda x : 
                    'Urgent'
                    if 'Urgent' in x
                    else 'Unflag_urgent'),
            # assign second column and use .map() on name column
            myfilings_flag = lambda x : x.name.map(
                # perform if-else-based check
                lambda x : 
                    'My Filings'
                    if 'My Filings' in x
                    else 'Unflag_myfilings'),
        )
)

print(res.filter(["name", "urgent_flag", "myfilings_flag"]))
```

Result like this:

```
                      name    urgent_flag    myfilings_flag
0                  [Order]  Unflag_urgent  Unflag_myfilings
1        [Hearing, Urgent]         Urgent  Unflag_myfilings
2   [Pleading, My Filings]  Unflag_urgent        My Filings
3  [Discovery, My Filings]  Unflag_urgent        My Filings
4             [My Filings]  Unflag_urgent        My Filings
5                 [Urgent]         Urgent  Unflag_myfilings
6     [Urgent, My Filings]         Urgent        My Filings
```

The catch of this solution is, that the rowwise calculation you get with `.map()` makes this somewhat slow, what you will see with about 100k lines.

Alternatively, you could try to make this a two-step thing with converting the name column to `str` and using some function to find a substring, which should produce a Boolean, and in the second step `.map()` the Boolean to the respective values. Could be faster...

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
def fn(x):
    a, b, c = x.copy(), [], []

    if (
        ("Urgent" in a and len(a) == 1)
        or ("My Filings" in a and len(a) == 1)
        or (("My Filings" in a) and ("Urgent" in a) and len(a) == 2)
    ):
        a.append("Uncategorized")

    if "Urgent" in x:
        a.remove("Urgent")
        b.append("Urgent")
    else:
        b.append("Unflag_urgent")

    if "My Filings" in x:
        a.remove("My Filings")
        c.append("My Filings")
    else:
        c.append("Unflag_myfilings")

    return a, b, c


df[["name", "urgent_flag", "myfilling_flag"]] = df["name"].apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(fn(x))
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                             Message             name      urgent_flag      myfilling_flag
0  Extension of Time to Comply with Mandatory Dis...          [Order]  [Unflag_urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
1      I electronically filed the foregoing document        [Hearing]         [Urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
2                              Said oral examination       [Pleading]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
3                         In the event of this cause      [Discovery]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
4                            A true and correct copy  [Uncategorized]  [Unflag_urgent]        [My Filings]
5              A credible explanation of human error  [Uncategorized]         [Urgent]  [Unflag_myfilings]
6                             Oral examination error  [Uncategorized]         [Urgent]        [My Filings]
```